# Running python script from C# using cmd.exe is not completing the execution

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm trying to run a python script from C# as follows:

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = $"/C \"python {Constants.PythonScriptPath} --input-folder {directory} --output-folder {directory}\"";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The script is processing the files from the input folder into the output folder but the processed files count is less than the count when running the same command from the windows command line.

Is there anything that can terminate the execution when calling the cmd.exe from C#?

Comment: Are the paths absolute or relative? Relative paths might cause issues.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang I'm using absolute paths. I tried to log the command and tried it on windows cmd it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone faces similar issue :

This issue happened because the application was running in debug mode with visual studio. When publishing the app it's working fine.

Looks like the visual studio is terminating the execution after a specific Time / Memory.